# Error in Octave while trying to call function: Undefined near line 1 column 1

Tags: machine-learning, octave

When I am trying to call a function it gives me an error. However, I checked my destination path which is correct where my ".m" file is save.
Destination path: C:\Users\Soumaditya\Desktop\ML
File name: warmUpExercise[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UfI2r.png)

Comment: How is the fuction defined? Please, post the first lines of its code

Comment: Hello il_raffa, please find the  lines of code

function A = warmUpExercise()
A = [];
A= eye(5);
end

Comment: Please do *not* post code in the comments; edit & update your post instead.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably mistyping something.

At the matlab or octave terminal, from the directory where you expect your .m file to be, type the command `what`.

This will show you what is actually there which is relevant to matlab / octave.

Another possibility is that you named your function file one thing, but the name of the function inside the file has named it something else  (though, in this case, octave at least would probably have thrown a warning...)

Also make sure that your filename doesn't actually have any weird spaces in the name. A file `'myfunction.m '` is not the same as `'myfunction.m'` or `' myfunction.m'`

Comment: Hello Tasos, I double checked my file name and it seems to be ok and also I typed command what but nothing shows in my terminal. Can I help you with any other details

Comment: @Shubham If `what` doesn't show anything, it means there are no .m files in that directory. Check your directory again to make sure it's correct (remember small letters are treated differently to capitals).

Comment: Hurrah!!!@Tasos thank you so much i got the error. I am using camel case and I wrongly typed small letters. Thank you so much:)

Answer (score 0):

You will need to move all the scripts to the default directory for Octave files on your system, move to your home directory on the Ubuntu system.